# Wordpress - remove space between last section/content and footer

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm building a Wordpress site and there is a space between the last content section and the footer (site: http://www.imprero.com/wordpress/graffitx). I inspected the code and reviewed the potential paddings but couldn't figure out where is this space coming from.

[image]

Comment: can you post a pic showing the space to which you're referring?

Comment: the yellow part between the black part and the grey part at the bottom of the page https://puu.sh/rR0Jr/b9fa784c48.png

Answer (score 1):

In your last mk-main-wrapper-holder -> theme-page-wrapper -> theme-content class you have an empty p tag with margin bottom of 20px. Removing that style or the empty p tag should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using a content builder to make your updates easier. Although this is a good, easy-to-use approach, this adds a lot of unwanted pieces of code in your site, which takes your loading time up several seconds.

Anyway, it seems to be caused by a section you added without content. So, check the content you added in your page via WordPress admin and see if you can find any empty content sections in your Content Builder. Preferably, use the "Text" instead of the "Visual" tab if nothing is showing up via your Content Builder visual options.

I think this piece of CSS code is a good workaround, although not the best option (which would be removing the empty section in Content Builder):

```
#theme-page .mk-main-wrapper-holder:last-of-type .theme-page-wrapper .theme-content p { 
     display: none;
}
```

Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: Thanks - that obviously helped. The problem is that there is no content in the visual builder after the last section. I checked also the text editor and the last section is the mk-page-section-wrapper. Don't know where the next wrapper comes from with the p tag. Anyway - thanks for help!!!